# Relationship between Ricci and dimension

Tags: riemannian-geometry

For exemplo i read $Ric_{\overline{M}}(N,N)$ = n in imersion $\phi: M^{n} \to \overline{M}=S^{n+1}$. Why? What's the relationship?

Ric = Ricci tensor e N is a normal vector field

Comment: Where did you read this? Some further context would help.

Comment: For any vector in $S^{n+1}$, $\mathrm{Ric}(x,x) = n\|x\|^2$, but that is very specific here: $S^{n+1}$ has constant sectional curvature, and $\mathrm{Ric}(x,x)/\|x\|^2$ is the sum of the sectional curvatures of $n$ well-chosen planes containing $x$.

Comment: (for any **tangent vector of $S^{n+1}$**, sorry)

Comment: @Didier thanks, reference to "$Ric(x,x)=n ||x||^2"$ please!

Comment: Context is Jacobi operator associated to second variational formula for area. consider a imersion $\phi: M \to S^{n+1}$ so  operator associated to second variational formula for area is $J= -\Delta - |A|^2 - Ric_{\overline{M}}(N,N) \implies J= -\Delta - |A|^2 - n$

Comment: @FabricioGonçalves any reference on the curvature tensor and the Ricci curvature of the unit sphere